# Jmeter:-How to check performance of any website using jmeter if multiple sub url are request when user try to hit single URL

Tags: jmeter

When i hit the my website url it calls many suburl.I kept all URL in one transaction controller but it works fine for 1-2 user.But when i applied load like 100 user it shows huge response time.

Please let me know how to check performance when you have sub url(3rd party url calling).

Comment: Can you explain/show your requests

Comment: Suppose i have login script.While clicking login button it calls liferay and solor services.So in this situation i have to kept all url in one transaction controller.But when i am running the script with load.The response is too much high.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to keep all the embedded resources (e.g. sub urls) in a transaction controller. Let JMeter handle them for you.

Go to the advanced tab of the HTTP Request which hits your website's main page.

Set the **Retrieve All Embedded Resources** and **Parralel downloads** checkboxes. Set the number of parrallel downloads to 6.

[image: HTTP Request Advanced tab]

There is also no need to call 3rd party urls (e.g. google analytics) during the test of your website.
Specify the template for your website's url in the **URLs must match** field.

This will ensure that the generated load will only hit your website and not the 3rd party providers.

Comment: Actuly my application is using liferay+solor server.when i am login in application it calls both liferay and solor services.thats way i have to kept both server suburl in transaction controller.

Answer (score 0):

As per the description I suspect your server is not able to handle 100 User load, because most probably your application is overloaded and cannot respond faster.

What you can do, is increase your Load gradually, like 1,5,10,20 etc. and run your test. At one point of time, the TPS will increase till Server Capacity and then it will reach the limit. After that even if you increase the User, TPS will not increase and will result in High Response Time.

Answer (score 0):

If these are really 3rd-party URLs (which are not developed and controlled by your company) you should [exclude them from your load test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) as if your application is loading an external image and this image loads slowly you cannot do anything with this. You load test should solely focus on your application and nothing else.

If the 3rd-party URL is not "alien", to wit it's integral part of your application which belongs to it and response time increases as the load increases then congratulations on finding the [bottleneck](https://blog.qatestlab.com/2018/04/17/testing-system-bottlenecks/). You can report it as the performance issue.

It might be also good to provide more details on the problem, to wit:

1. What is the maximum number of users your application can support providing the maximum throughput - so called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html)
2. What is the reason for the performance degradation which could be in:

   - lack of resources on the application side like CPU, RAM, etc. - can be checked using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
   - configuration of your application, out of the box Liferay might be not optimized for high loads, you need to consider [Performance Tuning](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/deploy/-/knowledge_base/d/performance-tuning). The same applies to [SOLR](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/tips-and-tricks-to-maximize-apache-solr-performance-74e8ea4f5c8d)
   - code of your application might be not optimal, you can use profiler tools like [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) to detect the slowest parts of your application and determine the reason

Comment: This third party service are developed by my company. Actually my problem is when i execute the script when transaction controller is executed the response are coming from server.In result all sub URL are added and showing in result but when it was executed in browser its shows response time by subtracting the parallel request.

Comment: In this case consider replacing the Transaction Controller with the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)